# how do I get fileshares to mount after a wireless connection is established?

Tags: mount, fstab

Changed the computer from a wired to wireless connection for a few days. Now the network shares will not mount at boot. But they will mount with `sudo mount -a`. I tried adding `_netdev` but that made no difference.

Relevant line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.1.9/video/shows /media/tv cifs credentials=/home/media/.smbcredentials,_netdev,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

How do I get `_netdev` to work with a wireless connection?